# Refactor complex constructor that calls 'base' certain levels deep

Tags: c#, refactoring

Lastly, I'm reading a lot about Legacy code and how to treat it.
I have a sample project, which contains badly written code, and I would like to refactor it.

NOTE: There are no tests in place, so I would like to add some tests first to ensure that I don't break anything with refactoring but I don't know how to test it.

Given the following ULM diagram:

[image]

I want to write a UT's for the methods in the Manager class (NOTE: These are not displayed in the ULM).
The problem is that the Manager class requires a User object which inherits a few levels deep.

For simplicity, I've not completely drawn the whole graph, but let's assume that the constructor of the 'User' object needs multiple arguments, and all those arguments represents objects with such a inheritance chain.
I'm not allowed to use null, since these objects are used somewhere in the inheritance level and a 'Null Exception' will be thrown when I use 'null'.

I want to practice TDD for adding a change to the Manager class, but therefore, I need to be able to construct a 'Manager' class at first.
Refactoring all the rest to just make the Manager is not acceptable.

I know one technique, which is changing the 'User' argument to an interface, but it feels wrong to use an interface for a 'User'.

Any advice?

Comment: from the code, I assume that you need to have non-null `User` object, which is the first test you want to add. the rest would be go with the logic flow. for each part of the code, you need to create a test. start with the `if` statments, then go for the actual logic (process input/output) to make sure the results stay the same.

Comment: I am not clear, where is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I can't create a 'UserService' with a 'Null' object, and I can't create a 'User' with a 'Null' arguments. Image this chain going much longer, Do I need to build the whole tree of dependent objects just to make this testable ..

Comment: If you want to test the behavior of `UserService` without worrying about `User` you may be able to mock it with something like [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4)

Comment: A class diagram might be useful for describing this problem.

Comment: @Complexity, using mocking libraries (like, typemock and others) can help you deal with legacy code. I strongly not recommend to use them with new code but they are good fore dealing legacy code without tests where you have to handle existing code as is and don't want to rewrite it before you have some test coverage.

Another approach is to write integration and end-to-end tests that cover functionality of Manager class. Though it might be even more challenging and time expensive task if you don't have a testing helper library that cover your domain at hands.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `User` class violates the single responsibility principle and from the naming, behaves as both a POCO and a service.

If that's the case, creating an interface would indeed be the proper sort term solution, until you recfactor the `User` too and break it down to multiple classes. POCOs are not usually turned to interfaces though. Services are almost always turned to interfaces and loosely coupled.

If it only changes the state of itself though, then you can very well use it as it is. The idea is to test each class individually. If the User class has no external dependencies, I would start by creating the complex object, no matter the hustle.

If it's too much for now, you might create a `Fake` class. Extend the user like this:

```
public class FakeUser: User {

}
```

And provide with a fake object that will drive the execution of your `UserService`

Comment: The code above is just a sample.
In fact I have an object which I would like to test which have a single dependency, but that dependency has inheritance 10 levels down.
I need to do a LOT of setup code in order to be able to just call my constructor. So, interface to the rescue?

Comment: Check also the fake option. You can wrap the class with a fake and avoid the interface.

Comment: A Fake class would not be the solution right here, since the 'User' class has a constructor, the constructor of the 'Fake' class need to call the 'base' constructor.
That 'base' constructor will do some logic, so I need to do the entire setup in the 'Fake' class.
It just seems wrong to me to add interface all over the place just for the sake of being able to write Unit Tests ...

Comment: You'll need to do something dirty anyway. You can create an empty or alternate constructor in the User class that does nothing and call that base version in your fake. Fortunately, unit testing guides to better code so it does not allow for workarounds.

Comment: Please have a look at the ULM I've added in the original question. It might given you some additional insights :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is Proxy Design Pattern. You will need to create a ProxyUser that contains only needed properties and methods from User (I mean only things that Manager uses). Then in your unit test, you can mock that ProxyUser.

```
public class Manager
{
    public User User {get;set;}
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(User.Name);
    }
}

public abstract class BaseUser
{
    public virtual string Name {get;}
}

public class ProxyUser : BaseUser
{
    private User _realUser;
    public override string Name => _realUser.Name;
}

public class User : BaseUser
{
    public override string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And then, in your unit test, you mock BaseUser

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Inversion of Control refactoring. 
This will allow you to user an interface, in a way, that uses them in "pattern" that have been tried by others. (forgive me, if this comes of as patronizing I do not know your level of experience)

So you basically:

```
[Fact]
    public void ManagerTest()
    {
        // arrange
        MockedUser mockedUser = new MockedUser();

        // act
        Manager manager = new Manager(mockedUser);

        // assert 
        Assert.Equal("Firstname", manager.GetUser().GetFirstName());
    }


public class Manager
    {
        private IUser _user; 

        public Manager(IUser user)
        {
            _user = user;
        }

        public IUser GetUser()
        {
            return _user;
        }
    }


public class MockedUser : IUser
    {
        public string GetFirstName()
        {
            return "Firstname";
        }

        public string GetFullName()
        {
            return "Firstname Middlename Lastname";
        }

        public string GetLastName()
        {
            return "Lastname";
        }

        public string GetMiddleNames()
        {
            return "Middlename";
        }

        public void SetFirstName(string firstname)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void SetFullName(List<string> fullName)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void SetLastName(string lastname)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void SetMiddleNames(List<string> middleNames)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

public interface IUser : INames
    {
        void SetFirstName(string firstname);

        void SetLastName(string lastname);

        void SetMiddleNames(List<string> middleNames);

        void SetFullName(List<string> fullName);

        string GetFullName();

        string GetFirstName();

        string GetLastName();

        string GetMiddleNames();
    }
```

Now it technically doesn't, so far, what is inside User. It's replaced by an Interface. 
(You will likely have different methods :) )

It technically doesn't matter what the "real" IUser object does, your mock can just return some hard-coded junk.

And then as you implement IoC down the line, you can implement the unit test for the interface first. And then the refactor.

However, if you want to test the legacy code, you are caught in the restriction that the code must be tested as is, and that is just not easy to test.

You will have to do it the hard-way, first, and then refactor. 
But depending on your time-constraint that might not be effective.